# Copied worlds don't show up in Minecraft Pocket Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I cleared Minecraft PE's data and my worlds disappeared from the Minecraft worlds list. Before doing this, I copied my worlds files from `/games/com.mojang/minecraftworlds`. After clearing data, I tried to move the files of the two worlds back to the "Minecraft worlds" from "games", but when I entered Minecraft Pocket Edition, the worlds didn't appear. What can I do?

Answer (score -1):

If you have a backup, try restoring your Minecraft worlds from that. See if that solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the app is still looking for them internally.
If so, change the location to External. See if that helps.